# $$ is working fine in html but not when set innerHtml after fetching

Tags: javascript

But after fetching $$ \le $$ from another API
and targeting div from client side file and changing inner text or html to '$$ \le $$' is not working just rendering $$ \le $$

for example
get(link)
returns $$ \le $$
Selecting('div') inner html or Text = '$$ \le $$'
is rendering $$ \le $$ not <=

I have tried including https://www.mathjax.org/#demo
For example

```
<html language = e>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
       $$ \le $$ 
          //working fine i.e. rendering <=
    </div>
    <script source="./test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no MathJax in your example.